# How to the value of an index in a computed() array in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Hi there I'm fairly new to vue and can't figure out how to set the value of a computed array.

I have a component that takes an object that has sections that can be edited by the user. When a section is edited or added I'm trying to emit the object. It seems like there should be a `setIndex` method to the computed object but I can't find it:

```
const sections = computed({
  get() {
    if (props.modelValue.sections) {
      return props.modelValue.sections;
    }

    return [];

  },

//This is not called when: sections[0]="hello world" 
  set(value) {
    console.log(value)
    faq.value.sections = value;
    emit('update:modelValue', faq.value);
  },

//This doesn't exist but its what I'm trying to do
  setIndex: (index, value) => {
    console.log("setIndex", index, value)
    faq.value.sections[index] = value;
    emit('update:modelValue', faq.value);
  }
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't. A writable computed is responsible for reading/writing `value` property, it's clueless about the rest. You'd need deep watcher for that, and then it would still be tedious because you'd had to detect changes. This is likely XY problem, it's much easier to do this in a function that is responsible for setting a value for an index